# document.createelement not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am learning javascript,I have got struck with create element.It's not working in any of the browsers.This is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="cont">
<script type="text/javascript">
function hi()
{
    alert("hi");
}
function replace()
{
    var a=document.getElementById('cont');
    var b=new Element("form",{name:"pnrForm",action:"\frame.html",method:"post"});
    var c=new Element("input",{name:"lccp_trnname",type:"text",id:"lccp_trnname",size:"15",maxlength:"15",alt:"Train Name/Number"});
    var d=new Element("input",{type:"image",name:"getIt",src:"button-get-pnr.png",align:"middle"});
    b.appendChild(c);
    b.appendChild(d);
    a.appendChild(b);
}
replace();
hi();
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: Your code doesn't have `document.createElement` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code is expecting Mootools to be present. Try this:

```
<body>
<div id="cont">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<script type="text/javascript">
function hi()
{
    alert("hi");
}
function replace()
{
    var a=document.getElementById('cont');
    var b=new Element("form",{name:"pnrForm",action:"\frame.html",method:"post"});
    var c=new Element("input",{name:"lccp_trnname",type:"text",id:"lccp_trnname",size:"15",maxlength:"15",alt:"Train Name/Number"});
    var d=new Element("input",{type:"image",name:"getIt",src:"button-get-pnr.png",align:"middle"});
    b.appendChild(c);
    b.appendChild(d);
    a.appendChild(b);
}
replace();
hi();
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/) is not the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) and it is also not [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.createElement` (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WQaaY/1):

```
function replace() {
  var div = document.getElementById('div');

  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.name = "pnrForm";
  form.action = "\frame.html"
  form.method = "post";

  var a = document.createElement('input');
  a.id = "lccp_trnname";
  a.type = "text";
  a.name = "lccp_trnname";
  a.alt = "Train Name/Number";
  a.size = "15";
  a.maxlength = "15";

  var b = document.createElement('input');
  b.type = "image";
  b.name = "getIt";
  b.src = "button-get-pnr.png";
  b.align = "middle";

  form.appendChild(a);    
  form.appendChild(b);
  div.appendChild(form);
}

replace();
​
```